# Spring Boot Ribbon no instances found but it has its addresses

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I'm writing an application which uses Ribbon and I have error as below:

```
2017-07-22 19:05:22.742  WARN 9907 --- [nio-8091-exec-8] com.netflix.loadbalancer.RoundRobinRule  : No up servers available from load balancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=reservationManagement,current list of Servers=[<MY_IP>:8090, <MY_IP>:8082],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {defaultzone=[Zone:defaultzone;   Instance count:2;       Active connections count: 0; Circuit breaker tripped count: 0;        Active connections per server: 0.0;]
},Server stats: [[Server:<MY_IP>:8090;    Zone:defaultZone;       Total Requests:0;       Successive connection failure:0;     Total blackout seconds:0;        Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970;      First connection made: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970;  Active Connections:0;   total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0;     average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0; 95 percentile resp time:0.0;     min resp time:0.0;      max resp time:0.0;      stddev resp time:0.0]
, [Server:<MY_IP>:8082;   Zone:defaultZone;       Total Requests:0;       Successive connection failure:0;        Total blackout seconds:0;     Last connection made:Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970;      First connection made: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970;    Active Connections:0; total failure count in last (1000) msecs:0;     average resp time:0.0;  90 percentile resp time:0.0;    95 percentile resp time:0.0;  min resp time:0.0;      max resp time:0.0;      stddev resp time:0.0]
]}ServerList:org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.DomainExtractingServerList@54b38e96
2017-07-22 19:05:22.744 ERROR 9907 --- [nio-8091-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for reservationManagement] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for reservationManagement
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execut
```

Why does Ribbon say that there are no instances of reservationManagement while it prints in "current list of Servers" that there are two of them (which is true)?

I would be grateful for your answers!

PS. These applications are also visible in Eureka and when I use Zuul server it works good.

Comment: Any ideas? I would be extremely grateful!